# Why does getInputStream on HttpURLConnection to VirtualBox server hang unless I am actively using the VM?

Tags: java, virtualbox, httpurlconnection, freeze

So I have a virtual machine running via VirtualBox. It's Ubuntu and I don't have sudo privileges on the user I have access to. There's a server running that allows me to access pages via localhost/page.php on the VM. Ive set up the network preferences in VirtualBox as Bridged and my host (MacBook Pro) is on my WiFi network.

Now I'm trying to write a Java program, on my host machine,  that accesses the VM server and reads the pages. I'm using HttpURLConnection and then getInputStream and looking over the results through a BufferedReader line by line. The issue I'm having is that my java program, which I run through Eclipse on my host, hangs unless I go on my VM and move the mouse around or type or do something, then it continues. And the VM doesn't lock the screen or have any power management concerns, it's always up.

I've spent a lot of time searching online and have tried setting the cache property to false, limiting the content length, using NAT mode with port forwarding instead, setting the close connection property to true, using openstream instead. Nothing has fixed my problem, it seems so bizarre.

**TL;DR** I have to move my mouse or type in the VirtualBox guest machine for a program running on my host to be able to access a server (local to guest, bridged to host), using HttpURLConnection getInputStream, and read information from it.

Comment: Before assuming it's a Java problem, did you try to make a connection using a web browser from your MacBook Pro? And/or from `wget` on the Terminal?

Comment: Yea I've used the browser and curl and it works every other time and times out or hangs every off time. I wasn't sure whether it was a Java or VM issue so I tagged both.

Comment: Then you will probably gett better help at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like an Entropy issue, try adding  -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom to your startup when running your tests